# Access C# class variables with array like notation?

Tags: c#, class

I have a program in which a user types in the name of the variable they want to change. So we have this:

```
string user_input = "age";
```

And I have a class with the following:

```
class Jim{
    public static int age = 10;
    public static bool married = false;
    public static string name = "John";
}
```

I now want to print the value of the variable that the user entered. So since the user typed in `age` I want to print `Jim.age`. How can I convert `user_input` into something that lets me access the class. I really want to do `Jim[input_string]` like you can in JS, but I believe this is possible.

I would use a dictionary to store all of the variables associated with `Jim` but you can't make a `Dictionary` which maps as `<string, bool or int or string>`.

Comment: This really isn't the way you should be solving this problem. Some kind of binding, maybe. But trying to reflect based on user input is incredibly dangerous.

Comment: You might want to consider expando objects for this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: what's wrong with a switch statement?

Comment: @MyP3uK That wouldn't work here as the variables are static.

Comment: I am not sure if OP needs them to be static taking into account the nature of the data and the class. But you are right it won't work with static.

Comment: do you want to use something like `Jim["age"]` = 23 ?

Comment: @Selman22 yeah that's what I'm looking for

Comment: well, you could use an indexer, but you need an instance for that, unfortunately there is no static indexers, so you can't do that.

Comment: Are the fields meant to be static? If not you can use `Indexer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would use a dictionary to store all of the variables associated with Jim but you can't make a Dictionary which maps as `<string, bool or int or string>`.

Sure you can, a `Dictionary<string, object>`.  `string`, `bool`, and `int` can all be stored in a variable of type `object`.

Answer (score 0):

The normal way to do this would be to use reflection:

```
FieldInfo requestedField = typeof(Jim).GetField("age");
Console.WriteLine(requestedField.GetValue(instanceOfJim));
```

Unfortunately, you can't do this because your variables are static. Make them instance members and it would work. As commenters have noted, allowing users to perform reflection is not a very good idea, so you may want to rethink the use case in general.

You could also use a dictionary mapped to object, as Servy suggested.

Interestingly enough, it can work with static, as long as you put the method in the Jim class:

```
class Jim
{
   ...Member variables...
   public static GetMember(String name)
   {
      FieldInfo requestedField = typeof(Jim).GetField(name);
      return requestedField.GetValue(null);
   }
}
```

Again, not recommending this, but it will get the functionality you want.

In case you are wondering, the MSDN for FieldInfo.GetValue: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue.aspx)